# Can a custom Camel component use routes and other components internally?

Tags: apache-camel

I am considering developing a custom Camel component for a specific http-based service, in order to encapsulate some specifics of that service.
It would seem natural to implement my component in terms of its own route that does some transformations and then delegates to a `http4` endpoint.

However, the [Camel Documentation](http://camel.apache.org/writing-components.html)  does not cover the case of a component being implemented in terms of others, and seems to assume that components are implemented by non-Camel means. But it feels wrong to re-do the httpclient integration, since Camel already has this.

Can a component create its own routes and use other components? If yes, can anyone point to an example?

Comment: Yes you are free to do whatever you want in a custom component - its after all just Java code.

Comment: Being free to do whatever I want means that I can also do many stupid things... So I'm trying to find out how well this is supported by the Camel infrastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [camel-context](http://camel.apache.org/context.html) component you can define a route inside of camel-context component.