# Is it possible to use camel components within a custom component?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have recently started with Apache Camel, and we are looking into creating custom components to abstract a lot of logic and simplify routes, but some of this logic involves http requests and other portions that have an existing camel component we want to utilize.

Is it possible to call other components (e.g. the http component) from within our custom component's producer?

I did see this question ([Can a custom Camel component use routes and other components internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460115/can-a-custom-camel-component-use-routes-and-other-components-internally)) that mentions using the camel context, but how to you replicate the route call outside of a RouteBuilder?

Comment: Yes its Java code so you can do anything you like. For example in your custom component you can use Camel's ProducerTemplate to easily call another endpoint, or however you like.

Comment: Thanks Claus, I definitely wasn't expecting a response from you! :) I've been able to get the http component using the ProducerTemplate and the example below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import CamelContext, Exchange, ProducerTemplate and ExchangeBuilder.

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.builder.ExchangeBuilder;
```

You then need to create instances of the producer template and camel context. I am using spring boot, so I can just inject the dependencies.

```
@Autowired
private ProducerTemplate producer;
@Autowired
private CamelContext camelContext;
```

In your method definition, you need to create an exchange request with the ExchangeBuilder. You can create a body and add headers to you exchange message here.

```
Exchange exchangeRequest = ExchangeBuilder.anExchange(camelContext)
.withBody("Hello World!")
.withHeader("username", "jdoe")
.withHeader("password", "pass")
.build();
```

You can then call the send method on the producer object to tap into your route and capture the response.

```
Exchange exchangeResponse = producer.send("direct:startRoute", exchangeRequest)
```

Comment: Thanks a million, I was able to get this working within my custom component!